# Android share intent showing weird options

Tags: android, android-intent, share

For some reason when I start a share intent it's asking to share to like Bluetooth and google drive is there a better way to do this? Is this normal?

Here is my share code:

```
public static void share(String headline, String subject, String text, String imagePath)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
    if (imagePath.equals(""))
    {
        intent.setType("text/plain");
    }
    else
    {
        intent.setType("image/png");
        File f = new File(imagePath);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(f);
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", u);
    }
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", subject);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", text);
    Activity activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, headline));
    }
}
```

Here's an image of what is displayed

[image: Share intent]

Answer (score 0):

That list is everything on your phone that has declared that it can receive a share intent. This is perfectly normal

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal. When you create a share intent like this it will broadcast to all apps that are compatible and display them to the user.

This is directly from the documentation: "To send data to another activity, all you need to do is specify the data and its type, the system will identify compatible receiving activities and display them to the user (if there are multiple options) or immediately start the activity (if there is only one option)." http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html